# Any pointers to how to use Telerik RADGrid in C sharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

Can anyone give me any pointers for free tutorial on RADGRID or give me a simple example on how to create a RADGRID and bind it to data source.

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything you need to know about the control you can find on the website of telerik

[telerik grid demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="radG" Namespace="Telerik.WebControls" Assembly="RadGrid.Net2" %>
 <radG:RadGrid Visible="False" ID="RadGrid1" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" OnItemCreated="RadGrid1_ItemCreated"
        EnableAJAX="True" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" PageSize="3"
        Width="95%" AllowMultiRowSelection="True" GridLines="None" Skin="3D" HorizontalAlign="NotSet">
        <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages"></PagerStyle>
        <MasterTableView DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" PageSize="20">
            <RowIndicatorColumn FilterImageUrl="" SortAscImageUrl="" SortDescImageUrl="" Visible="False">
                <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
            </RowIndicatorColumn>
            <ExpandCollapseColumn ExpandImageUrl="" CollapseImageUrl="" FilterImageUrl="" SortAscImageUrl=""
                SortDescImageUrl="" Visible="False">
                <HeaderStyle Width="19px"></HeaderStyle>
            </ExpandCollapseColumn>
            <Columns>
                <radG:GridTemplateColumn FilterImageUrl="" SortAscImageUrl="" SortDescImageUrl=""
                    UniqueName="CheckBoxTemplateColumn">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" OnCheckedChanged="ToggleRowSelection" AutoPostBack="True"
                            runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle Width="30px"></HeaderStyle>
                </radG:GridTemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
            <EditFormSettings>
                <EditColumn InsertImageUrl="" UpdateImageUrl="" EditImageUrl="" CancelImageUrl=""
                    FilterImageUrl="" SortAscImageUrl="" SortDescImageUrl="">
                </EditColumn>
            </EditFormSettings>
        </MasterTableView>
    </radG:RadGrid>
    <br />

    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" ConnectionString="<%$ AppSettings:Main.ConnectionString%>"
        SelectCommand="select * from table '"
        runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```